# Executing dynamic Sql to create table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute below query but getting invalid identifier error

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table temp parallel (degree 4) nologging as 
select e.* from employee e where e.emp_id between r0 and r1';
/
```

r0 and r1 I'm passing as input variable of datatype number

Comment: I tried but it's giving error that bind variables are not allowed in data definition operations

Comment: I've tried this not working   PROCEDURE temp_prc ( r0 in integer,r1 in integer ) IS TEMP_TBL varchar2(4000); begin TEMP_TBL:='create table temp parallel (degree 4) nologging as select e.* from employee e where e.emp_id between :r0 and : r1'; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TEMP_TBL using r0,r1; end temp_prc;

Comment: Yes, you should get `ora-01027` error. @Reza Davoudian 's answer(even along with a Stored Procedure) would be suitable for your case I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL block try this:

```
DECLARE
  r0 number :=  100;
  r1 number := 1100;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp parallel (degree 4) nologging AS 
                     SELECT * 
                       FROM employee 
                      WHERE emp_id BETWEEN '||r0||' AND '||r1||' ';
END;
/
```

Comment: I edited the answer just now. run the block again please. @Aman Kumar Singh

Answer (score 0):

r0 and r1 are not bind variables: change to :r0 and :r1 and add USING clause to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. (read the online documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html)

Comment: I tried but it's giving error that bind variables are not allowed in data definition operations

Comment: Indeed I forgot this point, only for select, update, delete, ...
then you have to concat the values to built the string.

Comment: You mean like this right ? I've tried this not workingPROCEDURE temp_prc ( r0 in integer,r1 in integer ) IS  

TEMP_TBL varchar2(4000);
begin
  
TEMP_TBL:='create table temp parallel (degree 4) nologging as 
select e.* from employee e where e.emp_id'|| 'between '|| 'r0 ' ||'and ' ||'r1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TEMP_TBL;

end temp_prc;